# Apps Missing from Facebook Developer Account

Tags: facebook, accounts

About a month ago or so, my facebook account was temporarily suspended due to suspicious login activity (it was me logging in on my own phone via mobile web browser).

Anyways, I managed to verify my identity and subsequently changed my password. Everything else is fine but I have lost all the apps in my developer account which probably numbered between 20 - 30. I have tried submitting the problem in the facebook accounts section but have not gotten a reply since. Has anyone had a problem like this before and how can I get in contact with someone who will actually reply and can help with the problem?

Thanks

p.s. I have found another similar thread but they differed in that they lost their "developer" status and got their apps back after they signed up as a developer again. My facebook account is already signed up as a developer but the apps are nowhere to be found.

Answer (score 3):

There are 2 things you can try:

- Go to this page and see if your Apps show up: https://developers.facebook.com/appeal
- Ask in the official Facebook developers group: https://www.facebook.com/groups/fbdevelopers